# Solving simple inequality gets MMA into an infinite loop

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I was solving inequalities and here is a very simplified version of what I am seeing.

When you do the following, all is well.

```
  Reduce[3^n < 250, n, Integers]
```

However, if you do not specify Integer, it thinks that is a Boltzmann constant or unit conversion.

```
  Reduce[3^n < 250, n]
```

The same thing happens with Solve.

Here is a screen capture of the issue and it continues repeating this pattern

[image]

Is it somehow trying to do some indirection because it gets into a loop that does not terminate and you have to terminate and restart Mathematica. Even after restarting, the issue persists. Why?

MMA Version: 13.3.0.0, Windows 10, X86

**Update** From a fresh restart (shut down and restarted MMA)

[image]

Comment: `Reduce[3^n < 250, n]` returns an answer quickly, what do you mean by infinite loop?

Comment: In MMA 13.3 on Win10-64bit `Reduce[3^n < 250, n]` returns a result quickly. Can you include your version and what you mean by infinite loop?

Comment: On version 13.3.1.0 Windows 10, it returns `C[1] \[Element] 
  Integers && (Im[n] == (\[Pi] (1 + 2 C[1]))/
    Log[3] || (Im[n] == (2 \[Pi] C[1])/Log[3] && 
     Re[n] < Log[250 Sec[Im[n] Log[3]]]/Log[3]))`

Comment: @JasonB.: Screen capture added.

Comment: @MarcoB: Screen capture added.

Comment: In the screenshot, it looks like the bracket goes off of the top of the screenshot, and the problematic command is `In[2]`.  What was `In[1]` in your session?  I suspect that's the real problem.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: I restarted MMA clean and see the new screen capture - nothing else defined, no other commands - nothing, just that one command. If I add Integers or Reals, it works fines.

Comment: Can you tray with `Trace[....]` around the command? as others saying, it returns fast in V 13.3.1 and does not do any of the things you show in your screen shot. Very strange. Do you have chatGPT notebook enabled or anything like this?

Comment: @Nasser: As soon as I ran it with Trace around the command, I get what is expected $$\left\{\text{Reduce}\left[3^n<250,n\right],c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land \left(\Im(n)=\frac{\pi  (1+2 c_1)}{\log (3)}\lor \left(\Im(n)=\frac{2 \pi  c_1}{\log (3)}\land \Re(n)<\frac{\log (250 \sec (\Im(n) \log (3)))}{\log (3)}\right)\right)\right\}$$ Bizarre!

Comment: @Nasser: Well, I restarted, and even with Trace, it is failing. The error message is now a repeating "Interpreting unit "Magnetic Constant" which then cycles to "PlanckConstant" and seems to be cycling through constant names. No other trace information - stuck in this loop. However, it then eventually settles out to the correct answer with the Trace. What strange behavior.

Comment: Also worth checking if you have anything defined in your init.m file.

Comment: @flinty: I will look an see. Thanks.

Comment: Any chance the predictive interface is stepping in the way?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Interesting observation, but I do not recall doing anything to enable it, unless it is always enabled. Any way to heck for that condition?

Comment: I think there is a way to disable it when it first appears. Maybe also an option in Preferences.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: I toggled Editing Options ► Private Editing Options ► CodeAssistOptions ► “AutoPopupEnable” and now it seems to be working properly. I am not sure if that was the cause because I never changed the defaults, but so far, it seems to have worked. Thanks!